# Order of serialization in Java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have a class A gathering lists of classes B and C.
The class C contains an element of the list of classes B (the list in class A).

So I serialize the class A, and when I de-serialize it I find out that the attribute B is null (although it was not the case when I serialized it).

I think it's because of the order of serialization, e.g. the list might be serialized after the attribute of the class C, and therefore this attribute is null.

Do you think it is a possible explanation, and if that is the case : How can I specify the order of serialization (without redefining readObject) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code should not be nulling attributes of `C` after serialization. The only way to control the order of serialization **without** redefining `readObject` is to implement [`Externalizable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) and implement `readExternal` and `writeExternal`. Best of luck!

Comment: First you say “classes B and C,” then you say “the attribute B.”  I don’t understand exactly what is null.  Regardless, serialization should handle all of this flawlessly and order shouldn’t matter.  Consider editing your question and showing us the definition of the class which is not being deserialized properly.

Answer (score 3):

The object you pass to `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject` is written, during which any objects that are come across (i.e. non-transient fields) are written in a nested fashion. If an object has already been written, a backreference is written. In this way cyclic structures are supported. Deserialisation is the opposite of serialisation.

Your problem is not here.

I think you can specify the order fields are written by defining `serialPersistentFields` (if I've spelt that correctly), but it's always nested.